# Codename One - GUI builder memory leaks

Tags: memory-leaks, codenameone

Does anyone have memory leak problems in Codename One Designer, GUI builder. We've noticed that the tool occasionally consumes all available RAM and even crashes the system.

There is strange behavior if using GUI builder and simulator, multiple java.exe processes stays open with memory consumed.

Our configuration is:

- Windows 10 64bit Enterprise
- Java 1.8.0_77
- Netbeans 8.1

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the "Simulate" button. If you avoid it and use the simulator within the project and the preview as your guidelines you won't run into it.

This is a somewhat problematic issue to track and we are focusing our efforts on stabilizing the new GUI builder which uses a completely different infrastructure.